# how to get autocorrelation 0, when?

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation

I am a newbie in time series and I understood negative autocorrelation through this example http://www.pmean.com/09/NegativeAutocorrelation.html

> If you are looking at the amount of time a doctor spends with
>   successive patients, if the first patient finished faster than
>   expected, you are more likely to adopt a leisurely approach with the
>   second patient. If the first patient takes longer than expected, you
>   are more likely to rush with the second patient, trying to get back on
>   schedule.

Then, if I am correct... high positive auto-correlation (let's say 0.9)... would be: if the first patient took 5', the next/previous one takes 4' 59''.

Then, what would be an example of low auto-correlation (let's say 0.01)? I can't understand the logic behind it...

Comment: This means that after any value one expects any other value with equal probability.

Comment: A simple way to create a time series with zero autocorrelation is to randomly permute the values of *any* time series.